# Last story to feature luminiferous aether

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

We get a lot of questions here asking what the first story of a certain type is. This is an example of a different sort of question—the last story of a certain type.

The [luminiferous aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether) was an attempt to conceive of a medium through which electromagnetic waves could propagate. By the early 1900s, however, aether as a scientific theory was laid to rest, with special relativity and other theories offering more plausible explanations of wave propagation in vacuum.

**What was the *last* science-fiction story to treat luminiferous aether as a legitimate scientific theory?**

Things that don't count:

- Modern stories (about post WW2) that have luminiferous aether. They almost certainly are not holding forth aether as a real phenomenon. The exception would be if some advocate of aether as serious theory has written a sci-fi book.
- Fantasy stories that have something called aether, but which corresponds more to the classical element than to the 19th-century theory.

Comment: So, you're disregarding modern Steampunk stories, where the story's inhabitants believe the science of aether, but the author doesn't?

Comment: @Adeptus -  Exactly. Otherwise the question would be both trivial to answer (i.e. some fanfiction published today), and wouldn't tell us anything about when sci-fi started leaving aether theory behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" (1978) there are references to "sub-ether radio" and a "sub-ether sens-o-matic".

Failing that (as they are comedy), Doc Smith was still using ether-waves in the Lensmen books in the 1930s and 1940s.

> "They can't see us—our ether wall is still up and their spy-rays can't get through it from the outside, you know." - *Triplanetary, Chapter 7*

Comment: Could you add some quotes from Lensmen?

Comment: I've added a quote from Triplanetary, as that's the only one that's on Gutenberg, and I don't have my hardcopies with me.  The best quote would be from the discussion between Kinnison and the woman he's dancing with at the ball  a couple of chapters into of Gray Lensman, in which he goes into some detail about the ether and sub-ether.